# scapy how to check if a field is set

Tags: python, scapy

I'm building a layer with scapy. this layer has ConditionalFields:

```
class Foo(Packet):
    name = "Foo"
    fields_desc = [
             ConditionalField(BitField("bar1", None, 4),
                             lambda pkt: pkt.bar1 is not None),
             ConditionalField(BitField("bar2", None, 4),
                              lambda pkt: pkt.bar2 is not None),

             ByteField("bar3", 0x0), 
             ByteField("bar4", 0x0)
             ]
```

Now how can I check if bar1 is set? resp. bar2? The lambda function I wrote seem correct to me, and according to the documentation it is used that way, but it is not working. Do you have any idea how I could fix this? The idea is that if `bar1` and `bar2` are set when I instantiate the class Foo, it should be present in the packet, else not. I don't want to do 2 packets just for that case.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using `ConditionalField`s for their intended purpose. A `ConditionalField` is a field in which its existence is determined by some **other** field in the packet. See the following example:

```
ConditionalField(XShortField("chksum",None),lambda pkt:pkt.chksumpresent==1)
```

Notice that the `"chksum"` field's existence relies on the value of the `"chksumpresent"` field, not on itself.

Using two layers may be the best approach (even though you are trying to avoid this).  You can use the `guess_payload_class()` method to help with this: http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/wiki/BuildAndDissect

Your question is an interesting one (basically trying to set an `is_present="None"` as an indicator to whether a field should be present).  Unfortunately, to my knowledge Scapy does not currently have this functionality.